# What is the flag to show the nesting of views in a Mac app?

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, nsview

I have just spet the last few hours trying to find the flag to use in Terminal to launch an app with the colored outlines around the various view elements to show how they are nested. I know that Matt Gemmell covered it during the Cocoa Face Off session of NSConference 2009 (at about the 13minute mark in the video). Unfortunately I can't actually read what he types and he doesn't speak the exact command. I know it has to be in the Apple docs somewhere but the search system is currently not being of any use. It looks like her just adds `-showAllViews YES` to the end of the command to open TextEdit but that command has no effect in 10.6.6. I have also tried every other capitalization I can think of as well as using `view` instead of `views`. Every command opens TextEdit just fine but doesn't show the colored outlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-NSShowAllDrawing` and `-NSShowAllDrawingColor`:

```
/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit -NSShowAllDrawing 200 -NSShowAllDrawingColor cycle
```

- `-NSShowAllDrawing` sets the delay between drawing commands (allowing you enough time to see the drawing update)
- `-NSShowAllDrawingColor` sets the fill colour for the regions with pending drawing operations (see class methods on for `NSColor` for valid values, or pass it "cycle" to loop through all available colours).

Comment: Thanks, Not the exact answer I was looking for but allowed me to figure out what I was missing. the actual flag I was looking for was `-NSShowAllViews yes`, the NS is what I was missing.

Comment: Ahh nice! I'd forgotten you could pass them at launch time. You know, if you're doing iOS you can always use the Spark Inspector or iOS Hierarchy Viewer. I'm not sure if there are any that support Mac OS X apps though :-/